# Video blurry after dragging it to composition

Tags: after-effects

I am having an issue with a video that I am adding effects to. The video is clear when I import it, but when I drag it on to a composition, it gets blurry.

[image]

Comment: was the answer sufficient enough for you

Answer (score 4):

1. Your resolution is on a third
2. But most importantly, your video is 720 x 480 resolution but on a 1920 x 1080 timeline (so it seems), so you are scaling it to fit (you can't make up for a lack of resolution but upscaling your footage).

To get the right comp size, you can:

- **Drag your video file onto the little film icon** to the immediate left of the 8 bpc selector below your footage tree
- Or **create a new composition based on the dimensions of your footage**

*There is no real point in making 480 footage 1080, it will not increase the quality.*

Comment: good improvements ;)